# The speed of information propagation (classical, not quantum)

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, information, classical-field-theory

It seems to be a common statement in textbooks that:

"For a linear wave equation with the dispersion relation $\omega_k$, the propagation speed of information is given by the group velocity."

which is usually demonstrated by the propagation of a wave package centered around a specific $k$ (e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity)). But this seems far away from a proof that there is no way to transmit information faster than that.

Generically, assuming there is an upper-bound for the group velocity, is there a rigorous way to prove that it limits the speed of information propagation? Or how should one attack this problem?

Update: thanks to @freecharly, group velocity can be larger than the signal speed according to [Milonni's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=kE8OUCvt7ecC&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&). I would change the question then: for a generic dispersion relation, how does one decide the maximum speed for information propagation?

Comment: Such statement would be nonsense because it is easy to find dispersive examples where the group velocity is actually *negative* and neither things nor information can travel backward in time, or whatever negative group velocity might mean.

Comment: One can then change the question into: for generic dispersion relation, how does one decide the maximum speed for information propagation?

Comment: in RF communications one can view the leading pulse edge as the beginning of the information and normally that propagates with the group velocity but for that one must assume that the medium is not very dispersive. For this interpretation one must have that the group velocity be positive and the signal itself be narrow band so that the envelope is reasonably stable and does not change over the time of observation.

Comment: Envelop type argument is more like a heuristic than a proof to me: that couldn't (logically) exclude the possibility that some creative guys create a non-envelop type wave to transmit information in some way, that is faster than the envelope propagation.

Plus, even without stable envelop, I don't see why one couldn't try to send information in other ways, which could have an upper bound for the speed of information propagation.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no known proof that the group velocity limits the speed of information propagation. The only real limit is the speed of light. Even in situations where the group velocity is below the speed of light, there are usually wave components that propagate at the speed of light. See Wikipedia ["Front velocity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_velocity).

Comment: Could you please provide an explicit counterexample?

I am imagining a generic linear wave equation, not a physical system, so the concept of the speed of light couldn't come it.

Comment: @Yen-TaHuang - What do you mean by a "generic linear wave equation"? A system described by a simple wave equation $$\Delta \phi=\frac {1}{v^2} \frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}$$ where v is the speed of propagation? Here you have a linear dispersion equation  and group and phase velocities are equal.

Comment: Any linear PDE with finite order space and time derivative, with translational symmetry.

For example, I would accept $\partial_t^2 \psi=(\partial_x^2+\lambda \partial_x^4 + m^2) \psi$

Comment: @Yen-TaHuang - See Wikipedia on Front velocity; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_velocity and references given there.

Comment: I see, so that's a counterexample that group velocity exceeds the speed of information.
One can then change the question into: for generic dispersion relation, how does one decide the maximum speed for information propagation?

Comment: @Yen-TaHuang - If your generic dispersion equation describes a physical system that is causal, the maximum speed of information propagation is definitely below or equal to the speed of light. You could solve the time dependent boundary value problem (or an initial value  problem with localized amplitude) and see what the speed of propagation of a signal is.  This corresponds to the signal velocity considered by Sommerfeld as cited in ref. 1 in the linked Wikipedia article on front velocity. The easiest way to do this is to Fourier transform the wave equation you are considering.